# Is there a (hotkey) way to set the weight paint brush to the weight of a specific vertex?

Tags: weight-painting

I'm not very familiar with weight painting in Blender, so I might be overlooking something obvious.

In the usual program I rig in, I can use a hotkey (<kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd>) to set my weight paint brush to the clicked vertex's weight--e.g. if the brush was initially at default 100%, <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> a vertex weighted to some bone at 80% would set the brush weight to 80%. Can I do the same in Blender?

Comment: There should be an eye dropper tool in the weight paint menu you can use

Comment: Ohh, I didn't notice that before. It's a bit unintuitive to me right now since that doesn't show me the sampled weight until I return to the brush tool, but thanks!

Comment: Yeah weight painting could definitely use a QOL update, glad I could help, have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default 2.8X keymap it is <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> to sample weights in weight paint mode. The 2.79 keymap is set to <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd>

[image]

Comment: The hotkey was just what I wanted. Thanks! PS Follow-up question: Part of the reason I needed this was because painting certain vertices often leads to an undesired splash effect (I'd like a whole edge loop to be one consistent weight, without too much variance). How do I limit the splash--by the Strength slider?